# Trying to split cells in multiple columns into rows - UNNEST query

Tags: google-bigquery

Good day all,

I've found solutions on the site for similar problems with a single column, which helped me halfway through, but I'm stuck at the final part when I need to unnest the array.

Here is the query so far:

```
#StandardSQL
With Data AS
(
SELECT 'aaa' as Item, 'EA/BX/PA' as UOM, '1/10/100' as Factor UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb' as Item, 'EA/PA' as UOM, '1/50' as Factor UNION ALL
SELECT 'ccc' as Item, null as UOM, null as Factor 
),
SplitData AS
(
SELECT
Item,
SPLIT(UOM, "/") as UOM,
SPLIT(Factor, "/") as Factor
FROM Data
)
SELECT
*
FROM
SplitData,
UNNEST(SplitData.UOM),UNNEST(SplitData.Factor)
```

The result is:

```
--Row---+--Item---+--UOM--¦--Factor--+--f0_--+--f1_--
   1    ¦  aaa    ¦  EA   ¦    1     ¦  EA   ¦  1
        ¦         ¦  BX   ¦   10     ¦       ¦
        ¦         ¦  PA   ¦  100     ¦       ¦
--------+---------+-------+----------+-------+-------    
   2    ¦  aaa    ¦  EA   ¦    1     ¦  EA   ¦  10
        ¦         ¦  BX   ¦   10     ¦       ¦
        ¦         ¦  PA   ¦  100     ¦       ¦
--------+---------+-------+----------+-------+-------
```

etc, etc

What I want to see is this:

```
--Row---+--Item---+--UOM--¦--Factor--+
   1    ¦  aaa    ¦  EA   ¦    1     ¦
--------+---------+-------+----------+
   2    ¦  aaa    ¦  BX   ¦   10     ¦
--------+---------+-------+----------+
   3    ¦  aaa    ¦  PA   ¦  100     ¦
--------+---------+-------+----------+
   4    ¦  bbb    ¦  EA   ¦    1     ¦ 
--------+---------+-------+----------+
```

etc, etc

I get that the problem is the double unnest in my query which is trying to join each with each, but when I select the ItemCode only, I'm not getting the UOMs and Factors at all...

Any idea how I need to amend the query to get this result, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes (based on the example of sample data) that number of elements in UOM and Factor is the same

```
#standardSQL
SELECT item, u AS UOM, f AS Factor
FROM `project.dataset.data`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(UOM, '/')) u WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Factor, '/')) f WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row item    UOM     Factor   
1   aaa     EA      1    
2   aaa     BX      10   
3   aaa     PA      100  
4   bbb     EA      1    
5   bbb     PA      50
```

Comment: This is certainly a very elegant way of doing it, thank you! Unfortunately, it ignores item ccc, which I still need in the result query. However, a small modification fixd that: SELECT Item, Unnested.u as UOM, Unnested.f as Factor  
FROM Data
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT *
FROM Data
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(UOM, '/')) u WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Factor, '/')) f WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
) as Unnested
USING (Item)

Comment: sorry, that's not how I understood requirement from your example `in What I want to see is this:` section. so in this case - change `JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Factor, '/')) f WITH OFFSET` to `LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Factor, '/')) f WITH OFFSET`

Comment: oh, Simplicity, the most gracious of the goddesses! Perfect, thank you. Both answers give the right result but yours is certainly more elegant and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
With

Data AS (
    SELECT 'aaa' as Item, 'EA/BX/PA' as UOM, '1/10/100' as Factor UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bbb' as Item, 'EA/PA' as UOM, '1/50' as Factor UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ccc' as Item, null as UOM, null as Factor 
),

SplitData AS (
    SELECT
        Item,
        SPLIT(UOM, "/") as UOM,
        SPLIT(Factor, "/") as Factor
    FROM
        Data
)

SELECT
    *,
    Factor[offset(uom_offset)] as unnested_factor
FROM
    SplitData as sd
    cross join UNNEST(sd.UOM) as unnested_uom  -- use left join if you want to display 'ccc' Item
        with offset as uom_offset
```

one more:

```
With

Data AS (
    SELECT 'aaa' as Item, 'EA/BX/PA' as UOM, '1/10/100' as Factor UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bbb' as Item, 'EA/PA' as UOM, '1/50' as Factor UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ccc' as Item, null as UOM, null as Factor
),

SplitData AS (
    SELECT
        Item,
        SPLIT(UOM, "/") as UOM,
        SPLIT(Factor, "/") as Factor
    FROM Data
)

SELECT
    sd.*,
    unnested_uom,
    unnested_factor
FROM
    SplitData as sd
    left join UNNEST(sd.UOM) as unnested_uom
        with offset as uom_offset
    left join UNNEST(sd.Factor) as unnested_factor
        with offset as factor_offset
where
    coalesce(uom_offset, factor_offset, 1)
    = coalesce(factor_offset, uom_offset, 1)
```

Comment: Hi, Y.K. Thank you for taking a shot at this. Unfortunately, the second example gives me the same result as the one I've posted, and the first one does the same, only replacing UOMs with an offset number but still keeping the nested format :(

Comment: It should be the right solution - try replacing the `sd.*` with `Item`

Comment: Thank you @MartinWeitzmann excluding UOM and Factor from sd in the second example works like a charm!

Comment: Yes, you're left joining with unnested arrays, which repeats the parent row (that contains the same array) per entry in that array. You saw these repeated arrays ... and now excluded them